# Change the x axis with all months

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following code what do I need to update in order to receive in the x-axis the values in this order M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9, M10, M11, M12, M13, M14, M15, M16, M17, M18 (have 0 in months where no pabliation exist)

```
# Load the required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
    Month = c("M3", "M3", "M9", "M11", "M11", "M11", "M11", "M10", "M11", "M11", "M15", "M16", "M16", "M16", "M17", "M18"),
    VenueType = c("Conference", "Journal", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Conference", "Journal")
)

# Create a function to extract numeric values from "Month" column
get_month_numeric <- function(month) {
    as.numeric(gsub("M", "", month))
}

# Generate a vector of all possible months from M1 to M18
all_months <- data.frame(Month = sprintf("M%d", 1:18))

# Count the frequency of "Conference" for each month
venue_frequency <- data %>%
    filter(VenueType == "Conference") %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    tally() %>%
    mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = all_months$Month)) %>%
    arrange(Month)

# Manually specify the desired order for the x-axis labels
desired_order <- sprintf("M%d", 1:18)
venue_frequency$Month <- factor(venue_frequency$Month, levels = desired_order)

# Create a bar plot using ggplot2 with ordered months
ggplot(venue_frequency, aes(x = Month, y = n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
    labs(x = "Month", y = "Venue Frequency", title = "Conference Venue Frequency by Month") +
    theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Add `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)`. If that doesn't work, [edit] your question to show what is wrong with that image, then please @-ping me and we'll work through the issues (reopening as needed). Hope it works well enough, good luck!